# Github's action is not building react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, npm, github-actions

When I build (npm run build
"scripts": {
"build": "react-scripts build --passWithNoTests"
})
project on pc, it successfully builds.
But when I push changes, the building process fails on github

```
> log@0.1.0 build /home/runner/work/project/project
> react-scripts build --passWithNoTests

Creating an optimized production build...

Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.

Failed to compile.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! log@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build --passWithNoTests`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the log@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-08-17T06_51_55_527Z-debug.log
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It's yml file

```
name: Node.js CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ test ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ test ]

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      
    - name: clean cache
      run: npm cache clean --force
    - name: install
      run: npm ci
    - name: npm install
      run: npm install
    - name: build
      run: npm run test --if-present
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Im getting the same error i just had some more code which searched for the cache if found it would not npm ci I just commented that it started working I tried a lot I'm not sure why but its not using the cache

Answer (score 48, accepted):

GitHub Actions set `CI` environment variable automatically with `true` . Treating warnings as errors because of it. You can try like below.

```
- name: build
  run: npm run test --if-present
  env:
     CI: false
```

Happy automations!

Comment: Where exactly should we put those last two lines in the workflow file? Unlike OP I also have a step that runs the command `npm run build` followed then by `npm run test --if-present` and so simply putting `env: CI: false` after the test step still gives me the same error that it treats any warning as errors.

Comment: **Update on my own comment:** It's important that `env: CI: false` (with correct indentation) sits under the same `run` step that runs your `npm run build` command and not `npm run test`. Not sure if OP made a typo or his problem is a completely different one from mine, but this is what worked for me at least.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: @malthe.w I faced similar problem of process exit 1 but after setting env CI=false npm run build of react app worked fine why so? did not understand why it worked